# strings.xmlのデータをActivityを継承していないクラスにString形式で読み込む方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: android

strings.xmlのデータをActivityを継承していないクラスにString形式で読み込む方法を教えて下さい。

詳細：
　お世話なっております。
　
　現在、多言語対応前提のアプリを作ろうしております。
　その中で、SharedPreferencesに情報を記録しているのですが、strings.xmlの文字をActivityを継承しているクラスのなかでは、「getString」で読み込むことができました。
　ここで、今後のVerUpも考え、初期設定のみをまとめて記載したprifix.javaというクラスをつくり、そこから読み出す構造にしたいのですが、ここでうまくいっておりません。
 以下のコードで読みだしたところ、「文字」でなく「数字」が出力されてしまいます。
　「getString」で読み出せないため、「R.string.a1_name_string」の登録（？）数値が出てきてしまっていると考えております。
　このような場合、どのようにすれば期待通りの「文字」が読み込めるのでしょうか？
　アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

prefix.java

```
public class prefix {
//多言語対応用　res/strings.xmlをコードで読みこむ
static String title = String.valueOf(R.string.a1_name_string);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applicationクラスを継承したサブクラスを作成して、その中でContextオブジェクトを作成しておいて別のクラスから参照してはどうでしょうか。
Applicationクラスは起動時に呼び出されるクラスでアプリケーションで共有するオブジェクトを管理するのに便利です。

1.例として次のようにonCreateメソッドをoverrideしてContextオブジェクトを保存しMyApplication.getContext()でどこからでも呼び出せるようにします。

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

2.Application継承クラスは`AndroidManifest.xml`の`<application>`タグの中に`android:name=".MyApplication"`のように記述しておきます。

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
         ・・・
```

3.`getString`が使えないクラスからは以下のようにリソースにアクセスできます。

```
MyApplication.getContext().getString(R.string.app_name);
// 又は
MyApplication.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
```

Comment: Yukari Sakurai様
ご解答を頂きありがとうございます。

コードを実装しAndroidstudioにはエラーが無いのですが、アプリを起動させると「異常終了」してしまいました。
logには以下が表示されます。
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

現在、色々試しているのですが気になる点についてご質問させてください。

１　onCreate()ですが、そのままだとエラーになるので
　　onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);に変更したのですが、問題あり
　　ますでしょうか？

２　MyApplicationの追加にAndroidstudioで新規→Blank Activityを使用。
　　レイアウトやmenuなどは削除しております。
　　AndroidManifest.xmlも記載を確認しました。
　　問題ありますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: sinさんこんにちは。
1.'MyApplication extends Activity'になっていませんか？ApplicationクラスにはonCreate()メソッドはありますが、onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)メソッドはありません。
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

2.新しくプロジェクト作成したのでしょうか？sinさんが質問時に作成中だったプロジェクトで新しいJavaクラスを一つ作成すればよいのです。
projectのappの下のjavaの下のパッケージ名を右クリック > New > Java class > クラスを名を入力 > 上記コードをコピペでできませんか？

Comment: Yukari Sakurai様　申し訳ありません。ご指摘いただいたようにActivityにしておりました。今までApplicationを使用したことがなく、また、Activityの応用で回避できるかも？と試行錯誤していたので思い違いをしてしまったようです。本当に申し訳ありませんでした。
現在、コードを修正し動作ができることを確認出来ました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: いえいえ、動いて良かったです！

Answer (score 2):

「多言語対応前提のアプリ」と、「初期設定のみをまとめて記載したprifix.javaというクラスをつくり、そこから読み出す構造にしたい」というのがいまいち繋がらないのですが、リソースIDとその存在意義について。

---

`string.xml`に定義した文字列リソースは、`Resources`を経由してしか取得できません。`Activity`が`getString()`で文字列として取得する場合にも、`Resources`を経由しています。

`Resources`を取得するには`Context`が必要です。`Activity`は`Context`を継承しているので`getString()`が使えるわけです。

他にも`Context`を継承したクラスはいくつかありますが、アプリケーションが動作している期間と、`Application`オブジェクトが存在している期間は等しいので、通常`Application`の`Context`を用いて、`getResources().getString()`で文字列を取得するのが確実だと思います。（短命な`Context`継承クラスを利用するとメモリリークの原因になります）

---

なぜこのような仕組みになっているのでしょうか。

`R.string.hello`を、`res/values-ja/`ディレクトリの`string.xml`に、

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">こんにちは</string>
</resources>
```

`re/values-de`ディレクトリの`string.xml`に、

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Guten Tag</string>
</resources>
```

を定義した場合に、`getString(R.string.hello)`を実行した端末のロケール設定が日本語であれば「こんにちは」を返却し、ドイツ語であれば「Guten Tag」の文字列を返却するのです。

端末の文脈（ここでは所有者のネイティブ言語）を判断するので`Context`なわけです。

このような仕組みを実現するには、`R.string.hello`が常に一意でなければなりません。その一意の定数を生成するのがリソースIDです。これはコンパイル時に整数値を生成することで実現されており、値には再現性がありません。

つまり、`SharedPreferences`に永続化したとして、その値で再度`getString()`をしたとしても、`R.string.hello`であるとは限りません。

---

- `R.string`の定数から文字を取得するには、`Resources`を取得する必要があります。`Resources`は端末のコンテキストに応じて返す値を変えたいので、`Activity`や`Application`のような`Context`継承クラスを必要とします。
- `R.string`の定数値が`String`ではなく`int`なのは、それがリソースを一意に特定するためのIDだからです。
- リソースIDの存在意義は多言語対応です。この値はコンパイル時に生成される再現性のない値です。

Comment: quesera2様、お世話になっております。
詳細なご説明のおかげで何が起こっているのか理解することが出来ました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`Application`クラスあたりで初期化が必要ですが、私ならこんな感じで作るかもです。

```
public class Prefix {
    private static final Prefix INSTANCE = new Prefix();
    public static Prefix getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    private Prefix() { /* singleton */ }

    private String mTitle;

    public void init(Context context) {
        mTitle = context.getString(R.string.a1_name_string);
    }        
    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: fkm様、お世話になっております。
いつも勉強になるアドバイスを頂きありがとうございます。
今回は、私の理解力からYukari Sakurai様のコードを参考させていただきたいと思います。
こちらの方法も勉強し理解します。
ありがとうございました。